# Can you create a calendar group without creating a sharepoint site attached to it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

Can I create a group calendar without creating a site attached to it? I would like for sites to be limited to one and calendars added to it as needed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Each Office 365 group point to a SharePoint Online site, we cannot create Office 365 group without SharePoint site attached to it.

Why not use the Calendar app in the SharePoint site? Just create a Calendar list via Site content->Add an app as you need.

Comment: Hellofiona_MSFT I believe that will work great for the calendar we need. I did not know if the app section as I have not worked with sharepoint all that much. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Santi10, here is an article that talks about all the calendar options in SharePoint:https://sharepointmaven.com/a-review-of-all-the-calendar-options-in-sharepoint-and-office-365/, you can get more information in it. If the post helps you, you can mark it as answer.